# Angular js and pushState

Tags: angularjs

In my app I want to update the history without reloading the current route.

Basically this is working:

```
$location.hash("/some_path");
```

But it does reinit the controllers. And I don't need it to do that. We can see the view being reloaded and in the context of my app, it is a killer. I just want to update the history so that the view gets updated if the user presses the back button but that's it. Basically, I would like this to work:

```
$window.history.pushState(null, "", "/#!/some_path")
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, angular is crashing in this function

```
$rootScope.$watch(function $locationWatch() {...})
```

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: show source with minimal example via plunker

Comment: having same problem. here's an attempt at a plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/c0AEXBXAHz4ZqH4kIXyN?p=preview